# Software com custo. Ajuda?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Olá, pessoal!

Bom, minha situação é a seguinte: Tenho um programa e quero cobrar pelo uso, porém percebi que se eu deixasse gratuito existiriam mais clientes. Então pensei em limitar o sistema e cobrar uma mensalidade pelo que o usuário quiser a mais. Só que existem diversas opções de ferramentas que eu ofereço com um custo. Por exemplo:

- Valor inicial: R$ 0,00
- Função1: +R$ x,00 mensal
- Função2: +R$ x,00 mensal
- ...

Aqui é onde está o problema, como eu posso fazer um software desse tipo? Gostaria de gerar um boleto só no final do mês e não vários para cada função que o cliente quiser... Preciso de ajuda para bolar uma lógica

Eu gostaria de dar ao usuário a oportunidade de adicionar e remover funções... Assim ele poderia escolher o valor que deseja pagar de acordo com as necessidades dele...

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer algo do tipo? Já trabalharam desse jeito? Tem chance de dar certo ou existem opções melhores?

Comment: [Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3822/perguntas-sobre-modelos-de-neg%C3%B3cios-s%C3%A3o-considerados-on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você cobrar da forma que está pensando em fazer, não vai ficar nada legal para o usuário que está comprando. Imagina se cada mês chega uma fatura de um valor?! Não ia ser legal.

Sobre a forma de cobrança, faça pacotes com determinadas funcionalidade e valores fixos para os planos mensais e anuais. Assim você da ao seu cliente menos opção "forçando" à compra.

Sobre formas de pagamento, você pode usar de inicial o Pasgseguro, que já possui uma biblioteca pronta para os desenvolvedores e ainda o público já conhece. Esta opção cobra uma taxa, porém, você ganha tempo e descobre se realmente a ferramenta vai dar certo ou não.

Trabalho assim, pois tenho um serviço web também. Segui esses passos e, até o momento, está dando certo.

Espero que eu tenho ajudado.

Comment: Entendi Matheus Velloso!
Muito obrigado cara, acho que a ideia de criar pacotes é realmente melhor! O Pagseguro eu já estou usando ^^